# Как оставить в массиве элемент с максимальным значением

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-query

У меня следующие документы в коллекции

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":10,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":30
      },
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      },
      {
         "value1":30,
         "value2":14,
         "value3":50
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id": 2,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":10,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":60
      },
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":80
      },
      {
         "value1":30,
         "value2":14,
         "value3":70
      }
   ]
}
```

Мне нужно оставить один документ с одним элементом в массиве по следующим критериям:

```
values.value1 = 20
values.value2 = 12
values.value3  // максимальное значение из всех значений values.value3 во всех документах
```

Например, по вышеуказанным критериям должен получиться такой документ:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
      {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      }
   ]
}
```

Также, подойдет решение, просто сортирующие документы и элементы по указанным критериям. Чтобы первым документом был тот, в котором значение values.value3 максимально из возможных и первым элементом в массиве был объект с максимальным значением. Например:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "values":[
     {
         "value1":20,
         "value2":12,
         "value3":100
      },
      {
         elements...
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id": 2,
   "values":[
      {
         elements...
      }
   ]
}
```

Сделать это у меня получается, но я использую `$match`, `$unwind`, `$group`, `$redact`, `$sort` по несколько раз. Может быть кто-то предложит более правильную реализацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучший способ это запустить два запроса. Первый, чтобы нашел максимальное значение и второй, чтобы остался только документ, где `value3` равно этому значению.

## Решение для MongoDB версия 3.2 или новее:

Начиная с версии 3.2 [можно использовать](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#use-in-project-stage) оператор [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/), который возвращает максимальное значение для каждого документа в [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) этапе. Оператор [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) здесь возвращает массив `value3`.

Следующий этап в цепочке — это [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group), где нужно группировать документы и возвращать максимальное значение.

```js
var result = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "maxVal": { 
            "$max":  { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$values", 
                    "as": "value", 
                    "in": "$$value.value3"
                } 
            }
        } 
    } }, 
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "mval": { "$max": "$maxVal" } } } 
]);
```

Поскольку метод [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) возвращает [курсор](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/core/cursors/#read-operations-cursors), нужно использовать метод [`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) и оператор `[]` для получения значения.

```js
var maximumValue = result.toArray()[0]['mval'];
```

Теперь можно использовать это значение, чтобы  оставить в массиве только элемент с максимальным значением. Для этого нужно использовать оператор [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)

```js
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
    { "$match": { "values.value3": maximumValue } }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "values": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$values", 
                "as": "value", 
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$value.value3", maximumValue ] } 
            }
        } 
    } } 
])
```

---

## Решение для MongoDB версии 2.6 или новее:

Решение для версий с 2.6 по 3.2  менее эффективно. Сначала в первом запросе нужно денормализовать массив `value3` сразу после `$project`,  используя оператор [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind). Последний этап в цепочке это `$group`, где группируем документы и возвращаем максимальное значение `value3`

```js
var result = db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { 
        "value3": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$values", 
                "as": "value", 
                "in": "$$value.value3" 
            } 
        } 
    } }, 
    { "$unwind": "$value3" },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "mval": { "$max": "$value3" } } } 
]);

var maximumValue = result.toArray()[0]['mval'];
```

Чтобы оставить в массиве только элемент с максимальным значением, у нас есть два варианта:

1. Используя оператор [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)

   ```js
   db.collection.aggregate( [ 
       { "$match": { "values.value3": maximumValue } }, 
       { "$redact": { 
           "$cond": [ 
               { "$or": [ 
                   { "$eq": [ "$value3", maximumValue ] }, 
                   { "$not": "$value3" } 
               ]}, 
               "$$DESCEND", 
               "$$PRUNE" 
           ]
       }} 
   ])
   ```
2. Используя оператор `$project` и [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)

   ```js
   db.collection.aggregate( [ 
       { "$match": { "values.value3": maximumValue } }, 
       { "$project": { 
           "values": { 
               "$setDifference": [ 
                   { "$map": { 
                       "input": "$values", 
                       "as": "value", 
                       "in": { 
                           "$cond": [ 
                               { "$eq": [ "$$value.value3", maximumValue ] }, 
                               "$$value", 
                               false 
                           ]
                       } 
                    }}, 
                    [false] 
                ]
            } 
       }} 
   ])
   ```

Comment: Привет @s.s ! Нужна помощь по агрегации, как с вами связаться?